# Where can you find the Laravel debug information?

Tags: laravel, debugging, environment

On my running application, there was a wrong configuration in production.
A user of the application informed me that there was a bug and he showed me a screenshot with lots of debug information including the content of my entire .env file.

I'm pretty sure that the following configuration was responsible for this issue:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Now I can't figure out how the user was able to view the debug information. I found some information about a Laravel Debugbar, however that extension isn't installed on my application. How can you check the debug settings of Laravel (the output of the screenshot I've received looks somewhat like phpinfo() except the styling is 100% different)?

Any help on this issue is very much appreciated!

Comment: If the user gave you screenshot of file that should not be accessible to users in the production then it is serious problem. Production user can not have access to .env file. Is it possible for you to share some part of screenshot sent to you? BTW you can find logs in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Most likely the user got an error and because APP_DEBUG is set to true, the flip/whoops errors are displaying in the browser if the user got an error, which includes some .env variables. Just set APP_DEBUG to false. The log level can still be ‘debug’, APP_DEBUG is for browser level error reporting while developing.